# create a 2 column list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an unordered list with two columns. I have googled a lot and found ways to do it with list items. This works when the text is short but when there is long texts (*more than one paragraph*), the list creates 3 rows and 1 right and one left column each (http://jsfiddle.net/MKTt6/)

```
#faq article li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: If you have trouble styling/positioning a certain element or set of elements, perhaps you've used the wrong element. My opinion is that the structure of the content of your page is not suitable as an unordered list. Instead, you should convert them to `<div>`s.

Comment: That doesn't look like a proper usage of lists...

Comment: Should I just do tables then?

Comment: Why would you use tables?  You don't have tabular data.

Comment: As SpikeX already suggested you might want to use DIV elements for your situation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MKTt6/1/ still didn't get any luck in this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use floats for this. Instead use `display:inline-block`

```
#faq article li {
    width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:-4px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. it helped me out a lot! There was one problem with it - the text was a little in the middle, so I added `vertical-align: top;` works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear left one of them out of two:

```
li:nth-child(odd) {clear:left;}
```

Comment: browser support for `nth-child` might be an issue. http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: Keep moving on and serve polyfill script via CC for older IE. :) This is not a real issue.

Comment: no-js support is an issue then. Though, this all depends on site requirements though.

Comment: agreed :) size should help better

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/sdyjD/1/

I'm not sure if i would use ul for this. I would personally go for divs only.

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
          Txt
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
          Txt
        </div>
    </li>
..... etc
</ul>
```

I use the inner divs for padding.

Css:

```
ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    list-style:none;
}

ul li div {
    padding: 10px;
}
```